# Avoid setting views as values for setTag in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a `ListView` and some image as list item. on click of any list item, I need to change the image source of `ImageView` of that particular list item.

I have successfully implemented this by setting the `ImageView` as tag to `convertView` and later getting the `ImageView` by tag and changing it's source.

I have set the tag as,

```
convertView.setTag(convertView.hashCode(), viewHolder.myImage);
```

But now it give me a warning as, `"Avoid setting views as values for setTag: Can lead to memory leaks in versions older than Android 4.0".`

So how to avoid this? or what can be a better alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `View.setTag(Object)` method to set the `ViewHolder`.
and onClick(View) use `View.getTag()` to get the `ViewHolder` and access the `ImageView` you want to change it image.

```
...
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
   holder.image1.setImage(...);
}
```

Comment: Yes this do works! But won't it affect performance as we are storing more data as tag?

Comment: No, tag dos not save the data its save a reference for the object. actually using setTag(key,object) takes more space, because you save them on a SparseArray

Comment: @JafarKhQ is there any limit for setting data using setTag()?

Comment: @AshishTiwari View.setTag() will replace any previous Object sited for this View. Its doesn't matter how large the Object is, its only save a reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved that way.

So, this is bad for SDK<4.0 and should not be used, unfortunately no solution was provided. Removing the references is not an option since it would decrease the performance due to the usage of the expensive View#findViewById(int) every bindView by a handful of FPS depending on the complexity of your list cell.

One solution is to go back using the ViewHolder pattern (which you might have already heard of) plus an additional field for the data object. The normal View#setTag(Object) method is not evil because it stores the data as plain non-static member mTag.

see more here: http://developer.sinnerschrader-mobile.com/handling-android-lint-warning-potential-leak-when-using-settag/399/

```
private static final class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    // ...
    Object data;
}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    if (holder == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.icon));
        holder.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text));
        // ...
    }
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(someImage);
    holder.textView.setText(someText);
    //...
    holder.data = someData;
}
```